# process substitution not working in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am stuck with weird issue. Process substitution is not working when it's been called from bash script, however it work when I shoot it from terminal.

Here is example: While running over terminal.

```
terminal>echo "$x"
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l

terminal>echo "$y"
1
2
3
4

terminal>paste <(echo "$x") <(echo "$y") -d' '
a b c 1
d e f 2
g h i 3
j k l 4
```

Here is example: Sample script

---

```
    #!/bin/bash
    x='a b c
    d e f
    g h i
    j k l'


    y='1
    2
    3
    4'

    paste <(echo "$x") <(echo "$y") -d' '
```

---

When I above script , I get following error:

```
test: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test: line 12: `paste <(echo "$x") <(echo "$y") -d' ''
```

Following are the details of shell I am using.

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.47(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
```

Is there any alternate way to bypass this issue ? Not necessarily I want to stick to process substitution.

Desired o/p:

```
a b c 1
d e f 2
g h i 3
j k l 4
```

Comment: Your script works in my bash 4.3.30 on Debian jessie. Is the script you posted the real script you tried to execute?

Comment: exactly the same.

Comment: It is working fine, did you check for `CRLF` DOS endings? copied from Windows editors may be?

Comment: @Inian , yes, I did that....

Comment: I gave up finding what is wrong in this, is there any alternate approch to join two variables by column-column ?

Comment: Works perfect - check it online in red hat machine : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMblNDeUR6cTM1XzA

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou , I have made similar things  work for years ,but I do not know why it not working in this case, hence the question :)

Comment: The script should also work in `zsh` and probably other shells. You could check whether it works with one of these on your system.

Comment: I am sure that you know how to work with such things, i just made the test in another machine and it worked. BTW process substitution does not work when bash is in POSIX mode.... Could that be the case?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou , Plese put this comment as answer. your comment made it work ,I just turned `posix` off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Process substitution does not work when bash is in POSIX mode. Please disable POSIX and try again.

To disable: This will cause process substitution to work .

```
set +o posix
```

To enable: : This will cause process substitution not to work.

```
set -o posix
```