# GitHub Actions: which shell for codecov-bash on Windows?

Tags: python, github, code-coverage, github-actions, codecov

What settings do we need to upload with GitHub Actions when running on Windows?

I've tried these.

## With no `shell:`

```
    - name: Upload coverage
      if: success()
      run: |
        bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      env:
        CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        CODECOV_NAME: ${{ runner.os }} Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
```

gives:

```
Run bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.5.4\x86
    CODECOV_TOKEN: ***
    CODECOV_NAME: Windows Python 3.5
At D:\a\_temp\f9f81a44-97d3-4908-8e7c-7d8d676e9d93.ps1:2 char:6
+ bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
+      ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

These settings work for Ubuntu and macOS.

## Adding `shell: bash`

```
    - name: Upload coverage
      if: success()
      run: |
        bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      env:
        CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        CODECOV_NAME: ${{ runner.os }} Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      shell: bash
```

gives:

```
Run bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  shell: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.EXE --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.5.4\x86
    CODECOV_TOKEN: ***
    CODECOV_NAME: Windows Python 3.5
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
##[error]Process completed with exit code 127.
```

## Changing to `shell: cmd`

```
    - name: Upload coverage
      if: success()
      run: |
        bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      env:
        CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        CODECOV_NAME: ${{ runner.os }} Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      shell: cmd
```

gives:

```
Run bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  shell: C:\windows\system32\cmd.EXE /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "{0}""
  env:
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.5.4\x86
    CODECOV_TOKEN: ***
    CODECOV_NAME: Windows Python 3.5
The system cannot find the file specified.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have better luck using the already existing [codecov action](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action).

In any case, you are running your action in a windows environment, so I would suggest not relying too much on unix-specific behaviour (i.e. [process substitution `<()`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection)) because this may require support from the underlying OS to work. Try this:

```
- name: Upload coverage
  if: success()
  run: |
    curl -s https://codecov.io/bash -o codecov.bash
    ./codecov.bash
    # OR
    # curl -s https://codecov.io/bash | bash
  env:
    CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
    CODECOV_NAME: ${{ runner.os }} Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
  shell: bash
```

---

You may also be getting the error as a result of the shell running in posix mode. See this question: [process substitution not working in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224070/process-substitution-not-working-in-bash-script/43224583)

Comment: Thanks, it works! I used `curl -s https://codecov.io/bash | bash`.